# How to move file from server to local MinIO bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, minio, minio-client

I have an EC2 server with MinIO object storage system installed, and I downloaded some files to the server using wget command. How to move the files from the server to a bucket?

I found the bucket path, but **access is denied**, it says:

```
$ mv testingdownload /mnt/data/miniodemo-bucket

mv: cannot move 'testingdownload' to '/mnt/data/miniodemo-bucket/testingdownload': Permission denied
```

What is the solution for this?